# iOS url multiple statements

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables

I have recently discovered that there is no way for me to access mysql with the pre defined iOS libraries.

So I have started making an app that has a web viewer (hidden) and will visit a url to pass the information to the database.

But I am having trouble making it so it visits a url that contains multiple variables from my objective c code my example is below.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://webpageurl.com/updatelocation.php?friendsphonenumber=%@&yourphonenumber=%@&message=%@", _friendsPhoneNumber.text, _yourPhoneNumber.text, _message.text];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[self.WebView loadRequest:request];
```

This is what the url should come out looking like

http://webpageurl.com/updatelocation.php?friendsphonenumber=1112223333&yourphonenumber=1112223333&message=hioehfoi

But my code is returning a error and I am a little unsure why any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to get a data from web server, the return value should be XML or JSON, not HTML. Then you can parse data with NSXMLParser or NSJsonSerialization. Also, you don't need to request on UIWebView. You better use NSURLConnection.

Comment: what error do you get?